# Why does the address of operator require an address to be returned from a function when it can be set to a normal variable?

Tags: c++

So here is my little class:

```
class test{
public:
    int& addressofx();
private:
    int x;
};

int& test::addressofx(){
    return x;
}
```

and here is main:

```
int main(){
    test a;
    int& foo = a.addressofx();
}
```

Why does the above compile fine, but when I make the function addressofx into a regular int function(not int&), I get errors?

You can do this:

```
int x;
int &y = x;
```

without getting the address of x, but when you return x from a function you need its address?  Why?

Comment: You first need to learn what is a reference in C++.

Comment: Study the difference between references and the address of operator, both of which use the symbol `&`.  There's also the bitwise AND operator (also using the symbol `&`) and (less compellingly) the logical AND operator (using the symbol `&&`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning the address of anything. You're returning a [**reference**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

This code will return an address:

```
class test {
    public:
        int* addressofx();
    private:
        int x;
};

int* test::addressofx() {
    return &x;
}

int main() {
    test a;
    int* foo = a.addressofx();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> int& addressofx();

This is returning a **reference** to an `int` variable.

> int& foo = a.addressofx();

This is declaring a non-`const` **lvalue** reference (**lvalue** means it has a variable name assigned to it, ie it can appear on the left side of an expression) that holds a reference to an int variable.  Since the function returns a reference to an int, the compiler is happy.

> when I make the function addressofx into a regular int function(not int&), I get errors?

A non-`const` **lvalue** reference cannot be bound to a temporary value (what `addressofx()` would return if you make that change). That is what **rvalue** references (introduced in C++11) are designed to handle instead, but you are not using that feature in this example.

> You can do this:
>   int x;
>   int &y = x;

Because you are declaring an **lvalue** reference and binding it to an **lvalue** variable. That is allowed.

If you change `addressofx()` to return an `int` (which is an **rvalue**, because it has no name so it can only appear on the right side of an expression), the return value cannot be bound to a non-`const` **lvalue** reference, because it is not a real variable.  However, it *can* be bound to a `const` **lvalue** reference (and the compiler will then extend the lifetime of the temporary beyond the function's return), eg:

```
int addressofx();
...
const int& foo = a.addressofx();
```

In short, you need to read up on how references work, and the difference between **lvalue** and **rvalue**.  Not all combinations can be used together.

Comment: doesn't addressofx() return a.x though? x is a member of a, which still exists in main() during the assignment so why is it considered temporary?

Comment: If `addressofx()` returns an `int&` then it returns the **memory address** of `a.x`. If it returns an `int` instead, it returns a **temporary copy of the value** of `a.x`.